# Fake device for screen share automated testing on Firefox

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, firefox, github-actions, screensharing

I am currently working on writing automated tests using **Selenium** and **Javascript**.
I would like to test screen sharing feature on our app with **Firefox**.
I would like to know how to use a fake device for this similar to these Chrome options:

```
  '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream',
  '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream',
  '--enable-usermedia-screen-capturing',
  '--auto-select-desktop-capture-source="Entire screen"',
```

I am using the following arguments for Firefox options:

```
'media.navigator.permission.disabled': true,
'media.webrtc.hw.h264.enabled': true,
'media.getusermedia.screensharing.enabled': true,
'media.navigator.streams.fake': true,
'media.peerconnection.video.h264_enabled': true
```

The tests work on my local machine with and without headless mode. However it fails in CI using **Github Actions**.
I noticed the screen sharing is actually sharing my own screen, so I assume the fake device didn't work for screen sharing (it works for camera and microphone by the way).

Environment:

- Selenium 4.12
- Firefox 117 (gecko driver and Firefox are provided by Selenium)